# Webdav server behind reverse proxy

Tags: webproxy, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We are running into an issue when locating the it-hit webdavsystem ajax browser  behind a reverse proxy.

In our case we are listening on port 8123, then serving up on port 443 from the outside.

It seems when we click on a folder in the ajax browser it’s responding on the listening port 8357 and not the requested port 443.

This is all hosted on Windows server in  IIS.

Anyone have a workaround?  Perhaps re-write the response URL's some how?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the server returning a complete url including server and port: http://webdavserver.com:0000/folder1/file.ext

This is a default setting for IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine and is done for maximum compatibility with WebDAV clients. Some versions of Microsoft Mini-redirector require complete urls and will not work with path only (/folder1/file.ext).

To disable complete urls you can set DavEngine.UseFullUris to false:

```
    var engine = new DavEngine
    {
        UseFullUris = false
    };
```

Any suggestions on how to tune Microsoft Mini-redirector to accept path only would be highly appreciated.